# 2001 Mitsubishi Mirage just died at red light

Tags: mitsubishi, cranks-wont-run, wont-stay-running

My son has a 2001 Mitsubishi Mirage and as he pulled up to a red light it died.. No pre warning, no hesitation nothing it just died . After that him and another gentleman pushed it out of the road and my son tried to get it to start again but it wouldn't. He ended up having to have it towed home. We are at a loss on why it died or what could be wrong or even where to begin I thought maybe the battery but we tried jumping it off and it still won't start... Any ideas...

Comment: What do you see and hear when you try to start it?

Answer (score 0):

With some info, there's a short list to check if you can perform them. A quick test for loss of fuel, spark or both; spray starting fluid while starting. A start means a fuel issue. No start can mean a spark or crank sensor issue. Pulling spark plugs can tell you if fuel is injected or not. And a spark test can tell you if spark is missing. Check for blown fuses too. No spark and dry plugs points to possible crank sensor failure since this sensor generates the electronic clock the ecm needs to operate the entire EFI system.